# cursor adapter implementation for autocomplete textview on android

Tags: android, textview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

In my app i need to populate email ids of contacts in an Auto complete textview. i got email ids in a cursor using content resolver. now i have to implement cursor adapter for auto complete textview for populate the email ids from the cursor. i have tried the following code but it didn't load email id from cursor.

my cursor adapter class is as follows:

```
public class AutoEmailAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AutoEmailAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    Log.e("adapter", "18");
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    Log.e("","bindview");
    String t = cursor.getString(1);
    Log.e("adapter @ 23", t);
    ((TextView) view).setText(t);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.e("","newview");
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
    String te = cursor.getString(1);
    Log.e("@33",te);
    view.setText(te);
    return view;
}

@Override
public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
    Log.e("","convertTostring");
    return cursor.getString(1);
}

}
```

android does not go beyond the constructor. The bindView,newView and convertToString methods didn't called.

in my main class i called the adapter class as in following way:

```
  AutoEmailAdapter adapter = new AutoEmailAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor_emailIds);
  emailId.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I do not know the reason why my code does not load email in the auto complete textview. please help me.

Comment: given that your newView is simply an inflate, why don't you extend a ResourceCursorAdapter instead ?

Comment: can you please explain in detail?

Comment: check ResourceCursorAdapter. It does the inflate for you, basically it would allow you to remove your newView and keep the bindView only (but that doesn't answer your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody i have solved by using Resource cursor adapter.